What is the meaning of "pranging" in this context? Is it US slang?
In the book Palace of Treason by Jason Matthews, I encountered the following sentence, that  I summarized to eliminate unnecesary information:

She weaved through the crowds of pedestrians in the red neon, pranging chaos of the boulevard.

What does "pranging" mean in this context? All I could find in the Cambridge dictionary was the verb "to prang", with the associated definition "to damage a vehicle slightly during a road accident".
Is this standard English? Is it US slang? What is the intended meaning?

The UD slang definition is probably intended.

A bit more context wouldn't hurt. Matthews seems to be American, but most definitions in Green's are British. Is the book British or American? How old is it? When is it set (red neon and boulevards don't typically go together)? You can roughly grok it from context (anything from loud to dangerous to overstimulating?) but maybe Matthews doesn't know what it means either.

'Prang' was also used in WW2 to mean crash-landing an aeroplane (airplane), which (if the pilot survived) might hit the ground several times. Perhaps the author intended to portray how she progressed down the street, with continuing collisions.

I think Weather Vane has the measure of it. Imagine someone trying to make their way on a crowded avenue, and not altogether politely.

...perhaps like "she barged her way..." to hurry somewhere or through a place in a rude and forceful way

The Cambridge Dictionary is using British Understatement. A prang is a crash, even a write-off.

She weaves through the crowd, and thus is the very opposite of pranging chaos.

I have only heard this used in British English; Monty Python particularly. An English pilot is describing how a German pilot crashed or collided his plane with another.  "Bally Gerry pranged his kite, did a waspy, feathered back on his 'how's you're father'." Since it was banter it was not meant to be understood, especially if it was said too slowly.

Possibly a misprint for "prancing".
